Hero web part drag and drop no longer working correctly
Suddenly our Hero web part is not working correctly in our Sharepoint 2019 on-premise. When you select and drag and drop the squares the correct squares' content doesn't go where you expect it to and the first square is not always maintaining the style (coloured block). When the main block is moved it takes the style of the main block with it to the smaller blocks - including the coloured square. This is occurring on all instances of the Hero web part, including on new blank pages an new instances of the web part. Has anyone else noticed this. I'm not sure if this coincided with a recent patch.
